# There is no .buildozer folder in my Ubuntu user folder

Tags: python, kivy, android-appwidget, buildozer

I want to program an android app using kivy 1.10, Python 3.6, the newest version of buildozer on Ubuntu 16.04 with VirtualBox.

Now I want to create an .apk file to load it up in the google store.

My problem: I used buildozer to creat an .apk but my User folder now only has a `.buildozer` folder and in it, not an `Android` folder.

User folder:

[image: User folder]

terminal:

[image: termial]

Comment: Don't link to external images of text. Cut and paste it into your question.

Comment: Look in the `bin` directory.

Comment: @JohnAnderson unhappily isnt there eather..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## apk file - location

The apk file can be found in the location/folder where you ran buildozer because the target location specified in your `buildozer.spec` is **`./`**

### Syntax:

cp source target

### Execution

```
cp /home/dennis/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/tschigg/bin/TSCHIGG-0.1-debug.apk ./
```

Comment: my .apk file has a size of 800mb. I have to reduce it under 100mb. What can I do ?

Comment: @Dennissaka, you should post a separate question for that and you will need to post much more info about your project. But just so you know, I have recently created 2 `.apk` apps using Kivy and the sizes are 10-20 MB.

Comment: @Dennissaka: Build your app using Buildozer for Python 2.

Comment: You mean install buildozer for Python 2 and than run buildozer Android debug? Should i uninstall buildozer for Python 3.x?

Comment: @Dennissaka: Don't uninstall Buildozer for Python 3.x . Uninstall it later you if you don't need it. In the meantime, use Kivy Buildozer VM which is Buildozer for Python 2. Install [Kivy Buildozer VM](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html) and Oracle VirtualBox.